# API gateway invoke URL dosen't load images in webpage

Tags: aws-api-gateway, http-proxy, asp.net-webpages

I have deployed simple web page in aws ecs container with public access. I can able reach the webpage via container public ip from browser. Now I Configuring api gateway with http proxy integration method. Provide endpoint url as public ip of container ex (http://52.12.14.25). After deployed the api,when I click the api invoke url the webpage not loaded properly. for example images in webpages not loaded.

[when access the webpage via public ip address](https://i.stack.imgur.com/l2Omo.png)
[when access the webpage via api invoke url](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Qz8BB.png)

Since I am new to API gateway, anything need to be configured for overcome this issue?

I recheck the API configuration with http proxy integration, looking for anything additional configuration required when do http proxy integration.